# MySQL AFTER INSERT Trigger doesn't get executed

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I am new to trigger and I need to insert 7 entries in a table. '_blood_bank_record' when one entry in table '_blood_bank' get inserted. So for that I had made a trigger which looks as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `blooddirdb`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `TrBloodRecord`$$

CREATE /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */ TRIGGER `TrBloodRecord` AFTER INSERT 
ON `_blood_bank` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT ;
  SET i = 0 ;
  WHILE
    i < 7 DO 
    INSERT INTO `_blood_bank_record` (
      `BBId`,
      `BloodGroupId`,
      `BloodRecord`
    ) 
    VALUES
      (new.BBId, i, 0) ;
    SET i = i + 1 ;
  END WHILE ;
END ;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

When I create this trigger, I am not getting any error but it also restrict the insert operation in '_blood_bank' which actually works when I drop this trigger.

Comment: According to the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f726/1) everything works as expected.

Comment: Ya i know that might be there is no error in the syntax but as i create this trigger, my '_blood_bank' insert's stored procedure gets executed but data is not inserted.
SO i am bit confused.